# Custom Properties converted to integers and driver links lost after restart

Tags: properties, drivers

I have made API defined custom RNA Properties in my Scene automatically added to a selected Object (not the Mesh).

But when I save the scene and restart Blender, they are already visible but the boolean properties where converted to integers and they are no more linked to the drivers where I defined them for.

Example for adding a driver target (property link to driver):

```
#Define a new Driver Target 
SubsurfViewTar = SubsurfViewVar.targets[0]                                  
#Define a new Driver id Type
SubsurfViewTar.id_type = 'OBJECT'                                           
#Define the Object which contains the custom property which drives the Property
SubsurfViewTar.id = bpy.data.objects[GrpName]                               
#Define the Custom Property of the object
SubsurfViewTar.data_path = "View_Resolution"
```

Comment: You will need to share your blend file for someone to see what is happening. Driver issues are often from [auto-run python scripts](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Security#Controlling_Script_Execution) being disabled.

Comment: autorun python scripts is not the problem as i know now... and the drivers exist like before but they are all set to 0 and no more linked to the properties